# Umbraco мультиязычность

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать мультиязычный сайт на  Umbraco. Необходимо, имея один сайт, заходить на него с разных доменов:

- www.mydomain.com переходим на английскую версию сайта;
- www.mydomain.ru переходим на русскоязычную версию сайта.

То, что уже сделал:

1. Настроил в ИИС два сайта:
   -lokalhost:8040 -- на английскую версию
   -lokalhost:8041 -- на русскую версию
   все они ссылаются на один сайт.
2. В административной части сделал два нода:
3. Домашня страница (в разделе язык и домены, присвоили язык английский и адрес домена lokalhost:8040);
4. Домашня страница2 (в разделе язык и домены, присвоили язык русский и адрес домена lokalhost:8041).

В общем, делал, как в http://blog.globalizationpartners.com/umbraco-multi-language.aspx.
Но, к сожалению, почему-то ничего не работает... При попытках зайти с разных хостов, я постоянно поподаю на английскую версию сайта.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении двигатся и что делать.
За ранее большое спасибо.

P.S. Как обеспечить перевод элементов управления в зависимости от версии сайта. На данном этапе все названия управляющих элементов записаны в файл ресурсов. Правильно ли это сделано и как настроить правильный выбор файла ресурсов в зависимости от языка?

Answer (score 0):

Хоть пост и старый, однако для новичков эта проблема до сих пор актуальна. Поэтому, отвечу.

Информация актуальна для Umbraco 7.

Согласно текущим рекомендациям Google для мультиязычных сайтов, следует сделать для каждого языка свою корневую страницу. Это вы уже сделали.

Далее, чтобы нужный домен ссылался на нужный корень, прописываем в разделе "Culture and hostnames" соответствующий домен. Это вы, как я вижу, тоже попытались сделать, однако на локальной машине.

Скорей всего дело в том, что не настроены привязки в веб-сервере, нету доменных имен и их отсылки к вашей CMS. Скорей всего все просто заработает на живом хостинге, если вы привяжете к нему два этих домена.